# The exported java code from selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-ide

After I export the Java code from Selenium ide.

After adding the Java code into eclipse, and including any other libraries required.
It keeps giving error about `ElementNotFound`.
And it is always the xpaths giving the error.

Does that mean that the Java code directly exported from selenium ide cannot work on eclipse?

Or are there any other special configurations or libraries that need to be added, inorder for the exported codes to work properly.

One thing to note: is that the entire test case is working smoothly in selenium ide. It is only causing error when running using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging the exported codes line by line.

I find that the `WebPageHandler` is automatically converted `DOM locator not installed`

So what you need to do, is to change the `DOM locator not installed`  to `cssSelector` or `xpath`